# ManagedExecutorService does not execute tasks

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to execute a task in a different thread using ManagedExecutorService inside Singleton EJB. However, the `run` method never gets executed. 
The application is deployed with Glassfish 5.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class MovieInventory{
    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @Resource
    ManagedExecutorService mes;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initConsumer() {

        mes.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                logger.info("test");;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Why might the run `method` never be executed?

Comment: Maybe log level is not info ;)

Comment: :) log level is set to info, this is just pseudocode, a task is not getting executed, I event put debug point but it is never executing code.

Comment: The problem is not in the posted code. Post a [MCVE]. You can also check if `initConsumer` is executed at all.

Comment: I changed the server to Wildfly and it is working fine. I think the issue here is with Managed Executor Service resource settings in Glassfish 5. I didn't have time to investigate further.

Comment: I had the same issue (managedexecutorservice/stateless bean/payara5). I suggest commenting the mes code and running the script inside without it. It may be another underlying error.